# Space of Jordan curves

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces

The space of square-integrable functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is well conceivable: it's essentially an $\infty$-dimensional Euclidean space (the [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) $L^2$) with well interpretable dimensions (= frequencies, modes).

But is there something like the *space of [Jordan curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve)* $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$? One might guess it's $L^2 \times L^2$, but that's not true, since being a Jordan curve imposes stronger restrictions on $f$, so the sought space $\mathcal{J}$ is only a subset of $L^2 \times L^2$. But what kind of subset? How is it shaped? Is it a subspace? Of which dimension?

[For me this a general problem: to imagine and understand "spaces of shapes": what is a sensible metric (→ metric space), how - eventually - to add and scale shapes (→ vector space), what's the dimension, and how to interpret the dimensions?]

Comment: Didn't you want to mean $\mathcal{J}$ as a subset of $C\times C$ where $C$ denotes the class of *continuous* functions $[0,1]\to\Bbb R$? as Jordan curves are continuous..

Comment: Well, in particular, every continuous function from a compact space to a finite-dimensional vector space is $L^2$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your motivation is geometric, it is natural to consider equivalence classes up to reparametrization. That is, to take the quotient of the set of homeomorphisms $f:S^1\to\mathbb R^2$ by the group of homeomorphisms $\psi:S^1\to S^1$, with the group action being composition ($f\sim f\circ \psi$). Of course, this moves the matter even further away from linear spaces. On the other hand, sensible metrics emerge, such as the simple [Hausdorff metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) and more sophisticated metrics which use the quotient structure. Efficient construction of geodesics between two given planar curves is a popular problem in this area.

The key word is *shape space* and while I do not know of a canonical reference for this subject, a simple [search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22shape+space%22+%22planar+curves%22) brings up a number of interesting articles.